# HTML form won't return a result

Tags: javascript, html

HTML form won't return a result. The javascript code for evaluating the form is near the bottom.

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" action="/" method="POST" onsubmit="evaluate(); return false;">
          Age: <select id="form-input-age" class="dropDown" name="age">
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="21">21</option>
            <option value="22">22</option>
            <option value="23">23</option>
            <option value="24">24</option>
            <option value="25">25</option>
            <option value="26">26</option>
            <option value="27">27</option>
            <option value="28">28</option>
            <option value="29">29</option>
            <option value="30">30</option>
            <option value="31">31</option>
            <option value="32">32</option>
            <option value="33">33</option>
            <option value="34">34</option>
            <option value="35">35</option>
            <option value="36">36</option>
            <option value="37">37</option>
            <option value="38">38</option>
            <option value="39">39</option>
            <option value="40">40</option>
            <option value="41">41</option>
            <option value="42">42</option>
            <option value="43">43</option>
            <option value="44">44</option>
            <option value="45">45</option>
            <option value="46">46</option>
            <option value="47">47</option>
            <option value="48">48</option>
            <option value="49">49</option>
            <option value="50">50</option>
            <option value="51">51</option>
            <option value="52">52</option>
            <option value="53">53</option>
            <option value="54">54</option>
            <option value="55">55</option>
            <option value="56">56</option>
            <option value="57">57</option>
            <option value="58">58</option>
            <option value="59">59</option>
            <option value="60">60</option>
            <option value="61">61</option>
            <option value="62">62</option>
            <option value="63">63</option>
            <option value="64">64</option>
            <option value="65">65</option>
            <option value="66">66</option>
            <option value="67">67</option>
            <option value="68">68</option>
            <option value="69">69</option>
            <option value="70">70</option>
            <option value="71">71</option>
            <option value="72">72</option>
            <option value="73">73</option>
            <option value="74">74</option>
            <option value="75">75</option>
            <option value="76">76</option>
            <option value="77">77</option>
            <option value="78">78</option>
            <option value="79">79</option>
            <option value="80">80</option>
            <option value="81">81</option>
            <option value="82">82</option>
            <option value="83">83</option>
            <option value="84">84</option>
            <option value="85">85</option>
          </select>
          <br><br>
          Gender: <select name="gender" class="dropDown" id="form-input-gender">
            <option value="" selected="selected">Female</option>
            <option value="" selected="selected">Male</option>
          </select>
          <div>
            <form action= "/submitted.html" method="get">
            <input type="button" class="form-button" value="Start" onclick="doTimer()" />
            <input type="text" name="seconds" id="seconds" />
            <input type="button" class="form-button" value="Stop" onclick="stopCount()" />
            <input type="button" class="form-button" value="Reset" onclick="reset()">
            <button type="submit" class="form-button" value="Submit" name="submit" onclick="evaluate(); return false" /> Submit </button>
          </form>
          </div>
          <script>
            function evaluate() {
              var age = document.forms["form1"]["form-input-age"];
              var gender = document.forms["form1"]["form-input-gender"];
              var time = document.forms["form1"]["seconds"];
              resultAnswer= ""
              if (time.value > 4.6 && time.value <= 6) {
                resultAnswer = "20s"
              } else if (time.value > 4.7 && time.value <= 6.1) {
                resultAnswer = "30s"
              } else if (time.value > 5.8 && time.value <= 9.4) {
                resultAnswer = "40s"
              } else if (time.value > 5.1 && time.value <= 10.3) {
                resultAnswer = "50s"
              } else if (time.value > 8.4 && gender.value == "Male" || time.value > 10.9 && time.value <= 14.5 && gender.value == "Female") {
                resultAnswer = "60s"
              } else if (time.value > 8.4 && gender.value == "Male" || time.value > 10.9 && time.value <= 14.5 && gender.value == "Female") {
                resultAnswer = "60s"
              } else if (time.value > 8.2 && time.value < 15 && gender.value == "Male" || time.value > 8.2 && time.value <= 17.8 && gender.value == "Female") {
                resultAnswer = "70s"
              } else if (time.value > 12.2 && time.value < 21.2 && gender.value == "Male" || time.value > 11.7 && time.value <= 22.7 && gender.value ==
                "Female") {
                resultAnswer = "80s"
              }
               document.getElementById('display-result').innerHTML = resultAnswer
            }
          </script>
        </form>
       </div>
      <div class="div-footer" id="div-footer">
        <h2>Results</h2>
        <h3>Your muscle age is in the:</h3>
        <p><span id="display-result"></span></p>
      </div>
```

Comment: when putting this in a jsfiddle the first thing that it highlights is the fact that button is closed at the start tag and that there is a /div too much (the last one might be due to only having a part of the complete page code, but the /button is caused by the / at the end of the opening tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**document.evaluate** is another function itself. Try changing the name and removing the onclick on submit button.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate